# Como faço para comparar um parâmetro do tipo objeto com outro(java)

Tags: java, classes, método

Tenho a o método addCurso que recebe um parametro que é um objeto tipo curso, nele tem informações como nome e área, isso tudo dentro da classe Faculdade, que possui um vetor onde serão adcionados estes cursos. Tenho que fazer a checagem antes de se, a posição do vetor estiver vazia, eu adciono, mas também se não houver nenhum outro curso dentro deste vetor com o mesmo nome. Como eu poderia fazer isto?

```
public class Faculdade
{
    private String nameFac;
    private int yearCreation;
    private Cursos []catalogoCursos;
    private Cursos[]cursosNovos;
    public Faculdade(String nameFacParam, int yearCreationParam){
     this.nameFac=nameFacParam;
     this.yearCreation=yearCreationParam;
     this.catalogoCursos=new Cursos[20];
     this.cursosNovos=new Cursos[5];
    }
    public void setnameFac(String nameAc){
        this.nameFac=nameAc;
    }
    public String getnameFac(){
        return this.nameFac;
    }
    public void setyearCreation(int year){
        this.yearCreation=year;
    }
    public int getyearCreation(){
        return this.yearCreation;
    }
    public void addCurso(Cursos novoCurso){
       for(int i=0;i<catalogoCursos.length;i++){
          if(catalogoCursos[i]==null){
              catalogoCursos[i]=novoCurso;
          }
       }
    }
    public void deleteCurso(String nome){
        for(int i=0;i<catalogoCursos.length;i++){
            if(catalogoCursos[i]!=null){
                if(catalogoCursos[i].getname().equals(nome)){
                    catalogoCursos[i]=null;
                    break;
                }
                else
                System.out.print("Curso não encontrado, ou não existente.");
            }

        }
    }
    public Faculdade(int yearCreation){
        this("Facs",yearCreation);
        for(int i=0;i<catalogoCursos.length;i++){
            if(catalogoCursos[i]!=null){
                if(catalogoCursos[i].getyear()>(getyearCreation()+5)){
                    cursosNovos[i]=catalogoCursos[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A classe curso:

```
public class Cursos
{
    private String code,name;
    private int duration;
    private float cost;
    private int year;

    public Cursos(String code, String name, int duration,float cost, int year){
        this.code=code;
        this.name=name;
        this.duration=duration;
        this.cost=cost;
        this.year=year;
    }
    public Cursos(String code, String name,float cost,int year){
        this(code,name,8,cost,year);
    }
    public void setcode(String code){
        this.code=code;
    }
    public String getcode(){
        return this.code;
    }
    public void setname(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getname(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public void setduration(int duration){
        this.duration=duration;
    }
    public int getduration(){
        return this.duration;
    }
    public void setcost(float cost){
        this.cost=cost;
    }
    public float getcost(){
        return this.cost;
    }
    public void setyear(int year){
        this.year=year;
    }
    public int getyear(){
        return this.year;
    }
    public void calculateCost(){
        float value=0,semestre=6;
        value=getcost()/(getduration()*semestre);
    }
}
```

Comment: Opa Marcela, insira na pergunta a base do seu código até o momento para que possamos utilizar para responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente adicionar uma nova condição ao seu `if` pra verificar se tem algum curso com o mesmo nome, o seu `for` ficaria assim:

```
  for(int i=0;i<catalogoCursos.length;i++){
      if(catalogoCursos[i]!=null && catalogoCursos[i].getname().equals(novoCurso.getname())) {
          return; //aborta um método void sem adicionar o novo curso
      }
      else {//Se ele chegar numa posição que é nula
         catalogoCursos[i] = novoCurso;
      }
   }
```

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza se é bem isso que a questão pede, pq só pode adcionar se não tiver outro curso igual.

Comment: Vou mudar um pouco o código pra ver se você entende melhor a implementação

Comment: Pronto, dá uma olhada aí, se tiver alguma dúvida pode perguntar!

Comment: Caramba obg brother gsauygs eu n tava entendendo pq vc tava colocando != mas agora entendi, obrigada mesmo!

Comment: De nada! Por favor clique na flechinha ao lado da minha resposta, a verde, isso me ajuda a  ajudar vcs!